# PySpark - String matching to create new column

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like:

```
ID             Notes
2345          Checked by John
2398          Verified by Stacy
3983          Double Checked on 2/23/17 by Marsha
```

Let's say for example there are only 3 employees to check: John, Stacy, or Marsha. I'd like to make a new column like so:

```
ID                Notes                              Employee
2345          Checked by John                          John
2398         Verified by Stacy                        Stacy
3983     Double Checked on 2/23/17 by Marsha          Marsha
```

Is regex or grep better here? What kind of function should I try? Thanks!

EDIT: I've been trying a bunch of solutions, but nothing seems to work. Should I give up and instead create columns for each employee, with a binary value? IE:

```
ID                Notes                             John       Stacy    Marsha
2345          Checked by John                        1            0       0
2398         Verified by Stacy                       0            1       0
3983     Double Checked on 2/23/17 by Marsha         0            0       1
```

Comment: Here is a fundamental problem. If your Notes column has employee name is any place, and there can be any string in the Notes column, I mean "Checked by John " or "Double Checked on 2/23/17 by Marsha " etc etc. There is no way to find the employee name unless you find the correct regex for all possible combination. Now theoretically that could be infinitely many. Plus if a new pattern comes how would you find correct regex for  that ?

Comment: can you split the string by "BY" and take the last index of the array returned?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

## In short:

> #### `regexp_extract(col('Notes'), '(.)(by)(\s+)(\w+)', 4))`
>
> This expression extracts ***employee name*** from **any position** where it is after **by** then **space(s)** in text column(`col('Notes')`)

---

## In Detail:

Create a sample dataframe

```
data = [('2345', 'Checked by John'),
('2398', 'Verified by Stacy'),
('2328', 'Verified by Srinivas than some random text'),        
('3983', 'Double Checked on 2/23/17 by Marsha')]

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['ID', 'Notes'])

df.show()

+----+--------------------+
|  ID|               Notes|
+----+--------------------+
|2345|     Checked by John|
|2398|   Verified by Stacy|
|2328|Verified by Srini...|
|3983|Double Checked on...|
+----+--------------------+
```

Do the needed imports

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col
```

On `df` extract `Employee` name from column using `regexp_extract(column_name, regex, group_number)`.

Here **regex**(`'(.)(by)(\s+)(\w+)'`) means

- *(.)*   - Any character (except newline)
- *(by)*  - Word **by** in the text
- *(\s+)* - One or many spaces
- *(\w+)* - Alphanumeric or underscore chars of length one

and **group_number** is 4 because group `(\w+)` is in 4th position in expression

```
result = df.withColumn('Employee', regexp_extract(col('Notes'), '(.)(by)(\s+)(\w+)', 4))

result.show()

+----+--------------------+--------+
|  ID|               Notes|Employee|
+----+--------------------+--------+
|2345|     Checked by John|    John|
|2398|   Verified by Stacy|   Stacy|
|2328|Verified by Srini...|Srinivas|
|3983|Double Checked on...|  Marsha|
+----+--------------------+--------+
```

[Databricks notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5537430417240233/3957787748072785/3506802399907740/latest.html)

### Note:

> `regexp_extract(col('Notes'), '.by\s+(\w+)', 1))` seems much cleaner version and [check the Regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/2lk6eV/3)

Comment: How can I include curly bracets in the second group - exp. (by{)?

Comment: @mrsrinivas - Can you please check "added Code" in my question and tell why Folder_num is not displaying any data in my frame? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602504/extract-values-from-spark-dataframe-column-into-new-derived-column

Comment: @AJR: Thanks for your post here. Please consider accepting/feedback answers to your previous questions.

Comment: how can i extract only 'C21618616' from 'ADRIANOPICCININIC216186162022-07-27 09:36:33Z'?
any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

### Brief

In its simplest form, and according to the example provided, this answer should suffice, albeit the OP should post more samples if other samples exist where the name should be preceded by any word other than `by`.

---

### Code

[See code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Qxfx0B/3)

**Regex**

```
^(\w+)[ \t]*(.*\bby[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]*.*)$
```

**Replacement**

```
\1\t\2\t\3
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
2345          Checked by John
2398          Verified by Stacy
3983          Double Checked on 2/23/17 by Marsha
```

#### Output

```
2345    Checked by John John
2398    Verified by Stacy   Stacy
3983    Double Checked on 2/23/17 by Marsha     Marsha
```

**Note:** The above output separates each column by the tab `\t` character, so it may not appear to be correct to the naked eye, but simply using an online regex parser and inserting `\t` into the regex match section should show you where each column begins/ends.

---

### Explanation

#### Regex

- `^` Assert position at the beginning of the line
- `(\w+)` Capture one or more word characters (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) into group 1
- `[ \t]*` Match any number of spaces or tab characters (`[ \t]` can be replaced with `\h` in some regex flavours such as PCRE)
- `(.*\bby[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]*.*)` Capture the following into group 2

  - `.*` Match any character (except newline unless the `s` modifier is used)
  - `\bby` Match a word boundary `\b`, followed by `by` literally
  - `[ \t]+` Match one or more spaces or tab characters
  - `(\w+)` Capture one or more word characters (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) into group 3
  - `[ \t]*` Match any number of spaces or tab characters
  - `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

#### Replacement

- `\1` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
- `\t` Tab character
- `\1` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the 2nd capturing group
- `\t` Tab character
- `\1` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the 3rd capturing group

Answer (score 2):

When I read the question again, the OP may speak of a fixed list of employees ("Let's say for example there are **only 3 employees** to check: John, Stacy, or Marsha").
If this is really a known list, then the simplest way is to check against this list of names with word boundaries:

```
regexp_extract(col('Notes'), '\b(John|Stacy|Marsha)\b', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dataFrame.withColumn("Employee", substring_index(col("Notes"), "\t", 2))
```

In case you want to use regex to extract the proper value you need something like

```
 dataFrame.withColumn("Employee", regexp_extract(col("Notes"), 'regex', <groupId>)
```

Comment: What if the employee name could be at the start, middle, or end of the string? Would this still work?

Comment: No, in that case you need to use regex. My solution strictly select the last one as the name of the employee.  But there has to be some pattern. If you want to use patten you can use regexp_extract(col("Notes"), <regex>, <groupNumber>)