# pyspark replace regex with regex

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to replaces a regex (in this case a space with a number) with

I have a Spark dataframe that contains a string column.  I want to replace a regex (space plus a number) with a comma without losing the number.  I have tried both of these with no luck:

> df.select("A", f.regexp_replace(f.col("A"), "\s+[0-9]", ' ,
>   ').alias("replaced"))
>
> df.select("A", f.regexp_replace(f.col("A"), "\s+[0-9]", '\s+[0-9] ,
>   ').alias("replaced"))

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some example inputs/outputs would be helpful. [How to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Comment: Can you elaborate the example with data. What is the actual value and what do u want to derive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySpark - String matching to create new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410887/pyspark-string-matching-to-create-new-column)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is another function, **regex_extract**

So, you have to divide the regex and get the part you need. It could be something like this:

```
df.select("A", f.regexp_extract(f.col("A"), "(\s+)([0-9])", 2).alias("replaced"))
```