# Parse a JSON column in a spark dataframe using Spark

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark

Input:

| caseid | object_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{'dummyAcc':'12346','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ1', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}] |
| 2 | [{'dummyAcc':'12347','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ2', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}] |
| 3 | [{'dummyAcc':'12348','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ5', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}] |
| 4 | [{'dummyAcc':'12349','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}] |
| 5 | [{'dummyAcc':'12350','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}] |

Output:

| caseid | schemeCode | CCZ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ZEROQ1 | SGD |
| 2 | ZEROQ2 | SGD |
| 3 | ZEROQ5 | SGD |
| 4 | ZEROQ | SGD |
| 5 | ZEROQ | SGD |

Kindly guide me achieving this output in spark, I am able to do this in python using a small sample data, but need to do this in spark due to data volume in production.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If the examples you gave here are representative of your use case, the fastest approach is to use PySpark's native `regexp_extract` tool. If your data is very complex you may need to write a UDF that casts them into dictionaries and searches them.

Comment: will regexp_extract work on JSON?

Comment: Sure. JSONs are just strings. Here's an example of using it to find the first word following a specific search word: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547701/1884171

Comment: the problem is that your data is not a valid JSON. Valid JSON use double quotes

Comment: @Steven, sorry my bad the data is in double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You might use `get_json_object`, its straightforward

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, """[{'dummyAcc':'12346','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ1', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}]"""],
  [2, """[{'dummyAcc':'12347','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ2', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}]"""],
  [3, """[{'dummyAcc':'12348','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ5', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}]"""],
  [4, """[{'dummyAcc':'12349','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}]"""],
  [5, """[{'dummyAcc':'12350','accountRequest':{'schemeCode':'ZEROQ', 'CCZ':'SGD'}}]"""]
], schema='caseid int, object_value string')

final_df = (df
            .select('caseid', 
                    f.get_json_object('object_value', '$[*].accountRequest.schemeCode').alias('schemeCode'),
                    f.get_json_object('object_value', '$[*].accountRequest.CCZ').alias('CCZ')))

final_df.show(truncate=False)
# +------+----------+-----+
# |caseid|schemeCode|CCZ  |
# +------+----------+-----+
# |1     |"ZEROQ1"  |"SGD"|
# |2     |"ZEROQ2"  |"SGD"|
# |3     |"ZEROQ5"  |"SGD"|
# |4     |"ZEROQ"   |"SGD"|
# |5     |"ZEROQ"   |"SGD"|
# +------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

So a coworker once told me that `regex_extract` is faster than parsing the JSONs and I've always believed that... until today when I decided to run some timing experiments comparing it the two  other solutions posted here using `get_json_object` and `from_json`.

The short answer is that all perform comparably, even when we complicate the JSONs by adding thousands of extra K:V pairs. The `regex_extract` method is actually consistently a bit slower in these tests.

**Setup: proving each method works**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fun
import pyspark.sql.types as t

case_ids = range(1,6)
data =  [
  '{"dummyAcc":"12346","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ1", "CCZ":"SGD"}}',
  '{"dummyAcc":"12347","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ2", "CCZ":"SGD"}}',
  '{"dummyAcc":"12348","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ5", "CCZ":"SGD"}}',
  '{"dummyAcc":"12349","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ", "CCZ":"SGD"}}',
  '{"dummyAcc":"12350","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ", "CCZ":"SGD"}}'
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"caseid": case_ids, "object_value": data}))

##
# fun.from_json
##
schm = t.StructType(
    [
        t.StructField("dummyAcc", t.StringType()),
        t.StructField(
            "accountRequest",
            t.StructType(
                [
                    t.StructField("schemeCode", t.StringType()),
                    t.StructField("CCZ", t.StringType()),
                ]
            ),
        ),
    ]
)

def run_from_json(df):
  return df.withColumn("object_value", fun.from_json("object_value", schm, options={"allowSingleQuotes": "true"}))\
          .select(
            "caseid",
            "object_value.accountRequest.schemeCode",
            "object_value.accountRequest.CCZ",
        )

##
# get_json
##

def run_get_json(df):
  return df.select('caseid', 
                    fun.get_json_object('object_value', '$.accountRequest.schemeCode').alias('schemeCode'),
                    fun.get_json_object('object_value', '$.accountRequest.CCZ').alias('CCZ'))


##
# regexp_extract
##

def run_regexp_extract(df):
  return df.withColumn("schemeCode", fun.regexp_extract(fun.col("object_value"), '(.)("schemeCode":")(\w+)', 3))\
    .withColumn("CCZ", fun.regexp_extract(fun.col("object_value"), '(.)("CCZ":")(\w+)', 3))\
    .select("caseid", "schemeCode", "CCZ")

##
# Test them out
##

print("from_json")
run_from_json(df).show(truncate=False)

print("get_json")
run_get_json(df).show(truncate=False)

print("regexp_extract")
run_regexp_extract(df).show(truncate=False)


from_json
+------+----------+---+
|caseid|schemeCode|CCZ|
+------+----------+---+
|1     |ZEROQ1    |SGD|
|2     |ZEROQ2    |SGD|
|3     |ZEROQ5    |SGD|
|4     |ZEROQ     |SGD|
|5     |ZEROQ     |SGD|
+------+----------+---+

get_json
+------+----------+---+
|caseid|schemeCode|CCZ|
+------+----------+---+
|1     |ZEROQ1    |SGD|
|2     |ZEROQ2    |SGD|
|3     |ZEROQ5    |SGD|
|4     |ZEROQ     |SGD|
|5     |ZEROQ     |SGD|
+------+----------+---+


regexp_extract
+------+----------+---+
|caseid|schemeCode|CCZ|
+------+----------+---+
|1     |ZEROQ1    |SGD|
|2     |ZEROQ2    |SGD|
|3     |ZEROQ5    |SGD|
|4     |ZEROQ     |SGD|
|5     |ZEROQ     |SGD|
+------+----------+---+
```

**Timing Part 1 -- Using Short JSONs**
I checked the wall clock time of running multiple iterations using the default compact JSONs defined above.

```
def time_run_method(df, n_it, meth, meth_name):
  t0 = time.time()
  for i in range(n_it):
    meth(df).count()
  td = time.time() - t0
  print(n)
  print("Time to count %d iterations: %s [sec]" % (n_it, "{:,}".format(td)))
  
for m, n in zip([run_from_json, run_get_json, run_regexp_extract], ["from_json", "get_json", "regexp_extract"]):
  time_run_method(df, 200, m, n)


from_json
Time to count 200 iterations: 15.918861389160156 [sec]

get_json
Time to count 200 iterations: 15.668830871582031 [sec]

regexp_extract
Time to count 200 iterations: 17.539576292037964 [sec]
```

**Timing Part 2 -- Using Long JSONs**
I added two thousand key-value pairs to the JSONs to see if the extra overhead of deserializing them would change things. It did not. Perhaps this structure is too simple and the internal parsers are able to simply avoid the extra keys or they just don't present a lot of overhead given how flat the structure is. I don't know.

```
cruft = json.dumps({k:v for k,v in enumerate(range(2000))})

data = [
  '{ "cruft": %s, "dummyAcc":"12346","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ1", "CCZ":"SGD"}}' % cruft,
  '{ "cruft": %s, "dummyAcc":"12347","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ2", "CCZ":"SGD"}}' % cruft,
  '{ "cruft": %s, "dummyAcc":"12348","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ5", "CCZ":"SGD"}}' % cruft,
  '{ "cruft": %s, "dummyAcc":"12349","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ", "CCZ":"SGD"}}' % cruft,
  '{ "cruft": %s, "dummyAcc":"12350","accountRequest":{"schemeCode":"ZEROQ", "CCZ":"SGD"}}' % cruft
]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"caseid": case_ids, "object_value": data}))

for m, n in zip([run_from_json, run_get_json, run_regexp_extract], ["from_json", "get_json", "regexp_extract"]):
  time_run_method(df2, 200, m, n)


    
from_json
Time to count 200 iterations: 16.005220413208008 [sec]
get_json
Time to count 200 iterations: 15.788024187088013 [sec]
regexp_extract
Time to count 200 iterations: 16.81353187561035 [sec]
```

Comment: Amazing answer, I have never stopped to think about which has the best performance

Comment: It just takes one slow day to exercise some curiosity :-)

Comment: Hi @andrew, thank you so much for this wonderful explanation, learnt something today. I will go with regex_extract as there are 500 k:V, I just took a sample and posted here.

Comment: 1. Have 2 question what is the 3 at the end of the regex_extract functions?   
2.  what if the scheme_code is like "schemeCode":"ZEROQ1 account (ABCD)" how will the regex change?

Comment: The 3 is the group number. `regexp_extract` captures all the groups specified in the regex. In this case we want the third group captured.

Comment: You don't need to change the regex when scheme_code looks like "schemeCode":"ZEROQ1 account (ABCD)" . The `(\w+)` group matches one or more _word_ characters. So it stops when it hits the whitespace after ZEROQ1.

Comment: @andrew, correct. But I want to capture till (ABCD) after which a different K:v pair starts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. If you want to capture the `ABCD` following `account` you could use: `.withColumn("account", fun.regexp_extract(fun.col("object_value"), '(.)("schemeCode":")(\w+)( )(\w+)( )(\()(\w+)', 8))`

If that doesn't do it you should probably post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To extract json-like data, use the function [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json).
It requires a schema as input. And your JSON is malformarted, therefore, you need to add the option `{"allowSingleQuotes": "true"}`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

schm = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("dummyAcc", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField(
            "accountRequest",
            T.StructType(
                [
                    T.StructField("schemeCode", T.StringType()),
                    T.StructField("CCZ", T.StringType()),
                ]
            ),
        ),
    ]
)

df.withColumn(
    "object_value",
    F.from_json("object_value", schm, options={"allowSingleQuotes": "true"}),
).select(
    "caseid",
    "object_value.accountRequest.schemeCode",
    "object_value.accountRequest.CCZ",
).show()

+------+----------+---+                                                         
|caseid|schemeCode|CCZ|
+------+----------+---+
|     1|    ZEROQ1|SGD|
|     2|    ZEROQ2|SGD|
|     3|    ZEROQ5|SGD|
|     4|     ZEROQ|SGD|
|     5|     ZEROQ|SGD|
+------+----------+---+
```