# PySpark regex to extract string with two conditions

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id  col1
1   ACC 12-34-11-123-122-A
2   ACC TASKS 12-34-11-123-122-B
3   ABB 12-34-11-123-122-C
```

I want to extract the code from the first and second lines (`12-34-11-123-122-A`, `12-34-11-123-122-B`) which have `ACC` before them.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547701/9500955) and this is my attempt:

```py
F.regexp_extract(F.col("col_1"), r'(.)(ACC)(\s+)(\b\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{3}\-[A-Z0-9]{0,3}\b)', 4)
```

I have to add the second group `(ACC)` because the `ABB` code has the same format.

How can I fix my regex to extract both `ACC` and `ACC TASKS` from this dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
(\bACC(?:\s+TASKS)?)\s+(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-[A-Z0-9]{0,3})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8pgHE/1)

Here `(\bACC(?:\s+TASKS)?)` matches `ACC` or `ACC TASKS` before matching a given pattern.

For your python code:

```sh
F.regexp_extract(F.col("col_1"), r'(\bACC(?:\s+TASKS)?)\s+(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-[A-Z0-9]{0,3})', 4)
```

Comment: I intended to change my third group `(\s+)` with `(.*)` but your answer is better.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^ACC(?:\s+TASKS)?\s+\d{2}(?:-\d{2}){2}-\d{3}-[A-Z0-9]{0,3}(?=-[A-Z]$)
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/C2nMEN/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^ACC(?:\s+TASKS)?\s+        ##Matching from starting of value ACC followed by spaces(1 or more occurrences) followed by TASKS and
                            ##keeping this non-capturing group as optional, followed by spaces(1 or more occurrences).
\d{2}(?:-\d{2}){2}-\d{3}-   ##Matching 2 digits followed by a non-capturing group which matches 2 occurrences of -followed by 2 digits;
                            ##non-capturing group is further followed by - and 3 digits -
[A-Z0-9]{0,3}(?=-[A-Z]$)    ##Matching capital A to Z OR 0-9 from 0 to 3 occurrences then making sure this is being
                            ##followed by a dash and capital A to Z at end of line/value.
```